# How to know where my question belongs to

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

Is there some decision diagram, how to determine where my question belongs to?

Often it's hard to decide if my question is for Superuser × Stack Overflow, Superuser × Android Enthusiast × Ask Different or something else.

For example: Now I'd like to ask *what are requirements for Firefox addon to be added into Firefox Android addon library*. I'm absolutely lost where to place it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to ask Firefox or Mozilla support. Not every topic has a place on Stack Exchange. [Su] is for problems specific to hardware or software you own or is in front of you, but not Web services or Web applications such as a Mozilla storefront. [So] is programming and other sites such as [Android.se] and [apple.se] are for devices that run operating systems from those companies.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+should+I+ask

Comment: @Mokubai This is the answer (post to linked Meta and use tag `site-recommendation`)

Comment: to me your question is not specific to [su] hence why I did not post an answer. I instead posted a link in a comment directing you to the "network meta" site where you should have asked your question. At best my answer would be "this isn't a question for SuperUser."

Comment: @Mokubai The question "what are requirements for Firefox addon to be added into Firefox Android addon library" is not the object of my question. It's only the example. The merit of my question is what to do when I'm not sure about site where to post my question. You showed me Meta.StackExchange (which I wasn't aware of) which is the right place for such questions. :) So I think this is the answer.